# Mmap failed with operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, memory, gpio, mmap

I've compiled application on Linux, but I got this error

> ```
> wiringPiSetup: mmap (GPIO) failed: Operation not permitted
> ```

After that:

I've added `iomem=relaxed` to grub

```
 cat /proc/cmdline 

 BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-88-generic
 root=UUID=da37e191-361e-4343-a63b-980e2696c8d6 ro iomem=relaxed
 console=tty1 console=ttyS0
```

But It didn't help.
How I can fix this issue?

Distribution:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: that wiringPi library tries to mmap `/dev/mem`, and only root can do that.

Comment: I always run command under root.

Comment: `true </dev/mem`  Works fine.


`28485 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC|O_CLOEXEC) = 3`
`28485 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 3, x3f200000) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)`
`28485 write(2, "wiringPiSetup: mmap (GPIO) faile"..., 59) = 59`  - Output from strace log.

Comment: That should be something related to Ubuntu; I'll add the tag, maybe someone who's running Ubuntu on the RaspberryPi can shed some light on this.